# How to create link for filling up form in MEW

Tags: myetherwallet

I have [link](https://www.myetherwallet.com/?to=0xC0b4ec83028307053Fbe8d00ba4372384fe4b52B&value=10&gaslimit=69161#send-transaction) for filling up forms in MEW. I want to generate link for deployment contract for this [page](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts). How can I generate link for filling up byte code in form?